# Cocoa - macOS Mojave - openHelpAnchor not working anymore

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-mojave

I have an application with a Help Book properly registered.
This application has contextual help buttons that - when clicked - display a specific chapter of the help using:

`NSHelpManager.shared.openHelpAnchor("chapter1", inBook: book)`

Since macOS Mojave 10.14, the buttons do not work anymore. It displays the Help window with: "Content unavailable".
I know the help book is properly registered since I can open the help via the traditional Help menu.

Any idea on what's changed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may have done already, but have you updated the helpindex? Remember you need to do it manually.

Comment: Yes I did, no change, unfortunately ! Thanks for the tip though